# Simple SVN checkout, D2NT Etal

Tags: svn, repository, svn-checkout

I'm trying to checkout the Diablo 2 D2NT Etal repo using their supplied URL:

`svn checkout 'http://www.projectetal.com/d2etal/Trunk'`

I am getting the error:

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://www.projectetal.com/d2etal/Trunk'
svn: E175002: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://www.projectetal.com/d2etal/Trunk)
```

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7, with SVN installed completely and correctly (I have other repos working just fine through Cygwin).

svn version: svn, version 1.7.1-SlikSvn-1.7.1-X64 (SlikSvn/1.7.1) X64

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using as a client? What version?

Comment: i just tried it with tortoise svn and it seems to work fine

Comment: '>svn list http://d2etal.projectetal.com/Trunk
D2NT/
Keypad List.txt
extras/' no errors from my side

Comment: @tq Yeah that's why I'm confused... But I'd like to avoid tortoiseSVN cause I'm an pretentious purist :P But really though, I have Cygwin on two machines, and use it for all my source control already.

Comment: `svn checkout http://www.projectetal.com/d2etal/Trunk/` ok for me

Comment: don't use TSN, use pure CLI svn, but - **native** and correct syntax

Comment: @LazyBadger Could you be a little clearer with what the command is and what it is doing? If it answers the question, also post it as an answer?

Comment: @LazyBadger The upped comment worked strangely enough. I tried that yesterday and it didn't... Such is life I suppose. If you post it as an answer I will accept it and up it.

Comment: my command differ only in trailing slash from you. And, well, my SVN is younger `svn, version 1.7.3 (r1242825)` `svn ls` works as local ls in Tux, but for subversion-repository tree, minimal transfer to client

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting the error on svn client "XML parse error at line 1 no element found" when accessing VisualSVN Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541520/why-am-i-getting-the-error-on-svn-client-xml-parse-error-at-line-1-no-element-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn checkout http://www.projectetal.com/d2etal/Trunk/` works.

Note missing '' around URL and added trailing / after trunk