# Why am I getting the error on svn client "XML parse error at line 1 no element found" when accessing VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, url, visualsvn-server

You may get the following error when using incorrect URL to access VisualSVN Server repository with a Subversion client, e.g. [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/):

```
XML parse error at line 1 no element found
```

*What is the cause and how to get rid of the error?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/). Most likely, you get this error because the URL to the repositories is not correct.

---

Unlike web browsers, Subversion clients are unable to access the content of the whole *repositories list*. In other words, you are unable to access e.g. `https://svn.example.com/svn/` URL using Subversion clients such as TortoiseSVN or a command-line client.

You must specify the **URL to a repository** (or it's subfolder or item) explicitly.

The correct URL should look like: `https://<servername>/svn/<repository-name>/`

---

**Update 05/07/2013:**

Repository Browser in TortoiseSVN 1.8 can list repositories offered by [SVNListParentPath](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra). See [TortoiseSVN 1.8 Release Notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#repobrowser).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i have fix this issue using de option "Steal lock" ( checkbox in bottom left area of the form when you are setting a lock to repository files ) this error is causaded beacause some files it seems to be unlocked but really it isn't ( verify this from de Explorer window clicking the properties of the file, and then, SVN Properties.... then you can see the real state of the file )[Lock the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzllP.png)