# Getting "invalid XML in the response" while checking out my project from github

Tags: svn, github, tortoisesvn

I was trying to get fresh copy of my project from github using TortoiseSVN client. But I am getting the following exception:

> The PROPFIND request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse
>   error at  line 1: no element found
>   (Checkout from https://github.com/anoopchaurasia/JavaScript-File-Manager.git)

When I try to checkout using Subclipse on Eclipse, it says `"Folder does not exist."`.

I am able to checkout same repository on my other system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SVN is different from Git. TortoiseSVN doesn't support Git. Use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use TortoiseSVN or a command-line SVN client to checkout a working copy from a Git repository.

This looks like a connectivity issue between the particular system and github. The error `XML parse error at line 1: no element found` usually means that the URL you enter is not correct. E.g. see this StackOverflow thread: [Why am I getting the error on svn client "XML parse error at line 1 no element found" when accessing VisualSVN Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11541520/761095) and read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/) .

Right now I was able to checkout the working copy with TortoiseSVN and command-line.

E.g. this works like a charm:

```
svn co https://github.com/anoopchaurasia/JavaScript-File-Manager
```