# TortoiseSVN unable to connect to repository when folder contains no files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN navigates my repository just fine except when I navigate to a folder that contains no files at which point it says...

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://www.blah.com/svn/'.
>   The OPTIONS request returned invlaid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://www.blah.com/svn/)

I don't have this problem when using a web browser.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11541520/761095

Answer (score -1):

The URL you enter is incorrect. You can't access a web interface (i.e. a list of repos) with SVN client. You must specify the URL to repository (or it's subfolder or item) explicitly.

See the SO thread that covers the same question: [Why am I getting the error on svn client "XML parse error at line 1 no element found" when accessing VisualSVN Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11541520/761095).